# Можно ли перезаписать произвольную часть файла?

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть файл и мне нужно перезаписать его середину.

Как я это могу сделать? Метод FileStream.Write пишет, как я понимаю только в конец...

Получается, что я должен читать исходный файл и копировать данные в новый файл, а потом когда дойду до нужного участка начать выполнять свои махинации?

Comment: *Метод FileStream.Write пишет, как я понимаю только в конец...* Нет. В точку текущего указателя. Который можно двигать методом Seek. Но надо учитывать, что при этом переписывается всё от текущей точки до конца файла - т.е. надо сдвинуться на оставляемый хвост, прочитать его, добавить его к записываемой части, сдвинуться на начало заменяемого фрагмента, и потом записывать. [FileStream.Seek(Int64, SeekOrigin) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileStream_Seek_System_Int64_System_IO_SeekOrigin_)

Comment: FileStream.Seek

Comment: Какой _формат_ у вашего файла? Дело в том, что некоторые форматы можно трюками и хаками изменить _сбоку_, не меняя самого содержимого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно заменить какую-то часть на такое же количество байт, то есть метод `Seek` (предварительно проверив установлено ли свойство `CanSeek`).

Если же заменить нужно на другое количество байт, то только поочередным копированием трех кусков - до заменяемого, замена, после заменяемого.